# How to avoid physical table overflows when updating DB varchar columns

Tags: database, db2, database-performance, database-administration, sqlperformance

Running DB statistics I see a lot of physical overflows when updating a table.
I believe the reason to be a varchar column that starts out as null, then later updated to a ~20 characters value. when that happens the record overflows from the physical page, so a new page is allocated, resulting in bad data locality until I re-org the table.

**how could I hint the DB to allocate enough space for the record in advanced, so that when I update its varchar column from null to a string it won't overflow?**

- I can't switch to a fixed length CHAR column type since I don't have a predefined max length.
- I rather not use a magic value instead of a null (say "00000000000000000000"), as a pre-allocator.
- My main use case is DB2, but would also like to know for MSSQL and oracle.

Comment: Your `VARCHAR(x)` does have defined maximum length, *x*.  Just like `CHAR(x)`.

Comment: Technically you're right. I meant to say that I don't have a predefined max length within the practical boundaries of varchar 2K-4K. I don't want to always pay 2K if I'll use CHAR.

Comment: The problem you describe here is a result of poor database/application design.  If solving that problem isn't in the cards, and you just want to put a bandaid on the problem, have you considered using a CLOB instead?

Comment: Why would I use a CLOB for a most cases 20chars, worst case (2K chars) column? The issue here is physical DB overflow: the row starts it life with a Null in the column. I just want the DB to know to expect that this column would change, and not allocate a new physical page for it.

Comment: ADDITION: In other words, CLOB would solve overflows but would destroy my select time performance.

Comment: As I said, you should solve the *actual* problem, not a by-product of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with this problem by mofifying the PCTFREE for the table that is updated contantly.

```
db2 alter table xxx pctfree 25
```

The PCTFREE is the percentage of empty space in a page, that is reserved for rows overflows. You have to find a good value for your table, in order to not waste space, but preventing the use of another page for row overflows.

For more information

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html
- http://www.dbisoftware.com/blog/db2_performance.php?print=139

Comment: The PCTFREE setting only takes effect during a reorg, so it doesn't seem much different from just doing the reorg after the updates.

Comment: I think the point is to reduce the frequency with which you need to perform the reorg.  This certainly won't eliminate it, though.

Comment: The question was 'how to allocate space to reduce row overflow when updating', and this is the purpose of PCTFREE. It is clear that to preallocate that free space it is necessary a reorg, but once the reorg is done, the pages could have enough space to  host the overflow instead of being stored in other page.

Comment: @AngocA default PCTFREE of 0 is a bummer. Would have been perfect if I could specify PCTFREE while creating the table. I have no knowledge as to when my customers are running reorgs, if it all.